# New method to MainWindow is not visible

Tags: c++, qt

I have added `st()` function to my `MainWindow` class. But why I can't call it?

Got error:

```
error: 'class Ui::MainWindow' has no member named 'st'
 ui->st();
     ^
```

*.h

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void st();
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();


private slots:
    void on_MainWindow_iconSizeChanged(const QSize &iconSize);

    void on_pushButton_4_clicked();




private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

*.cpp

```
void MainWindow::st()
{
}
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
ui->st();
}
```

Comment: `Ui::MainWindow` and `MainWindow` are not the same classes, I guess. You need to simply call `st();` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added method `st` to `MainWindow` class, but attempting to call method `st` on object `ui` which type is `Ui::MainWindow` - Qt autogenerated class.

If you want to call `st` method in `on_pushButton_4_clicked` then `ui->st()` should be replaced with `st()`.

Comment: Fine, but what if for some reason (call from static method for example) I need to call by using pointer to Ui::MainWindow ?

Comment: If you need to be able to call method from `MainWindow` - you should have access to it. It's not possible to access `MainWindow`'s methods having `Ui::MainWindow` pointer - they are 2 separate classes.